# How to identify the exchange to which the message is routed to in Spring boot rabbitmq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am new to Spring AMQP and was just trying to understand RabbitMQ java configuration using annotations. Here the sample code.

Sender code -

```
@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

So, here, in convertAndSend(), only the routing key is specified. There is no exchange name given.

The configuration file is as shown below-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    final static String queueName = "spring-boot";

    final static String HOST = "120.27.114.229";

    final static String USERNAME = "root";

    final static String PASSWORD = "root";

    final static int PORT = 5672;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }

    @Bean  
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {  
          CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
          connectionFactory.setHost(HOST);
          connectionFactory.setPort(PORT);
          connectionFactory.setUsername(USERNAME);
          connectionFactory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
          connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
          //����Ҫ����,��Ϣ�Ļص�
          connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true); 
          return connectionFactory;
    } 

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here, the TopicExchange bean is defined and the name is "spring-boot-exchange". So the sender sends message to this exchange?? If there are two exchanges, to which exchange does the sender send messages to ??
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are sending to the default exchange `""`:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
```

not your topic exchange.

To send to an explicit exchange, use

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("someExchange", "routingKey", "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
```

**EDIT**

Or, you can configure the default exchange to be something other than the default exchange. `template.setExchange("someExchange")`.

Comment: Thanks again Sir. But why is the topic exchange defined in the configuration then? I got a little confused as to why the topic exchange is defined if not being sent messages to. This is  the source which I am referring to. https://github.com/scalad/SpringBoot-RabbitMQ . Didn't understand as to why TopicExchange has been configured.

Comment: Every queue is bound to the default exchange `""` with it's name as the routing key. The `RabbitTemplate` is configured to send to that exchange by default. That exchange is not being used; you can, however, set the default exchange on the template `template.setExchange("myExchange")` to override its default. Perhaps the person that wrote that code doesn't understand?

Comment: Thank You Sir:) Because I came across more than 3 codes written this way on GitHub. So for sending, either the exchange name should be contained in convertAndSend, or it can be set on the template. These are the only ways to configure exchange. If not, default exchange is used wherein it routes to the queue whose name matches the routing key..Is my understanding correct??

Comment: Even the spring official site has the similar kind of code - https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Comment: That's wrong; I [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/issues/16).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answers. It really helped a lot Sir:)